# Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ which is decreasing on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ which is decreasing on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.Then from graphical approach it is clear that $f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in [0,1]$.But mathematically by using any theorem how we show that.//

Answer (score 3):

No theorem is  required. For any $x$ we have $0=f(0) \geq f(x) \geq f(1)=0$ so $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is (weakly) decreasing, therefore $0=f(0)\ge f(x)\ge f(1)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$